# I need information on this flower

Tags: flowers

What kind of flower is this and what does it need to grow
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like orange *Gerbera* daisies (Asteraceae).

They originate from South Africa, and like full sun. Advice is to water it in the morning, so the leaves can dry because they are sensitive to fungal infection. [Here](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/gerbera-daisy/growing-gerbera-daisies.htm) I found some more detailed care instructions.